# How to get number of visitors of a page on GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, analytics, visitors

I need to get the number of unique visitors(say, for the last 5 minutes) that are currently looking at an article, so I can display that number, and sort the articles by most popular.

ex. Similar to how most forums display 'There are n people viewing this thread'

How can I achieve this on Google App Engine? I am using Python 2.7.

Please try to explain in a simple way because I recently started learning programming and I am working on my first project. I don't have lots of experience. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Create a counter (property within entity) and increase it transactionally for every page view. If you have more then a few pageviews a second you need to look into [sharded counters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters).

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to increase the counter every time someone requests the page. I need to know the number of _unique visitors_ and the number should decrease when someone leaves the page.GAE gives you information about your visitors when you manage your application in admin panel. I was wondering if it's possible to use those logs from my application.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to tell when someone stops viewing a page unless you use Javascript to inform the server when that happens. Forums etc typically assume that someone has stopped viewing a page after n minutes of inactivity, and base their figures on that.

For minimal resource use, I would suggest using memcache exclusively here. If the value gets evicted, the count will be incorrect, but the consequences of that are minimal, and other solutions will use a lot more resources.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) service for getting statistics? Read [this article](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/09/whats-happening-on-your-site-right-now.html) about real-time monitoring using this service. Please note: a special script must be embedded on every page you want to monitor.